# Error handling in overlapped socket IO

Tags: c++, windows, winsock, overlapped-io

Can anyone please suggest a reliable way to handle system errors in case of using overlapped socket IO and IOCP?

MSDN description is cumbersome on this aspect. It says that for `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` return code FALSE there should be a subsequent `GetLastError` call to get error code on the failed operation. However, we know that for WSA-functions one should call `WSAGetLastError` instead (`GetLastError` returns 0 upon a socket error). So the first part of question is - how does it work in practice?

Another problem is handling errors if completion packets are extracted by `GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx`. MSDN describes only error handling for this call itself, saying nothing about obtaining error codes of individual failed operations.

Thanks in advance for all responses and comments.

Answer (score 2):

After few hours of experimenting and studying MSDN with a magnifying glass I've found the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684342%28v=VS.85%29.aspx (an article on OVERLAPPED structure, description of the `Internal` field):

> The error code for the I/O request. When the request is issued, the system sets this member to STATUS_PENDING to indicate that the operation has not yet started. When the request is completed, the system sets this member to the error code for the completed request.
>
> The Internal member was originally reserved for system use and its behavior may change.

The last phrase doesn't look good, but I guess it is what it is.